# MotionLayout for iOS

Tags: ios

Is there anything similar to `MotionLayout` for iOS?
I have created basic animations while scrolling, implementing `ScrollViewDidScroll` method, and wanted to know, maybe there is already an option to adapt something similar to MotionLayout in `UIKit`.

Comment: What is MotionLayout?

Comment: MotionLayout is a ConstraintLayout which allows you to animate layouts between various states. Its Android layout system.
here is an example of implementing it while scrolling, basically it binds view changes to scrollView scroll.
https://twitter.com/armanchatikyan/status/1037244566271877120

Comment: There isn't some "magic" built-in thing like that, but there are autolayout constraints and or "frozen" animations and you can certainly alter them in coordination with / response to scrolling. So no automatic binding but can be easily done with a small amount of code.

Comment: Thanks, I did some coding implementing ScrollViewDidScroll, and changed constraints based on scroll, just wanted to know, maybe there is official layout, or maybe third party lib, which would make me implement this kind of animations in a lot of screens, and not everytime implement that method and make all that calculation  from scratch. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think they finally came up with something like what you were looking for. This video provides a pretty decent overview and is provided by apple itself. You can actually see how they ripped off MotionLayout XD

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10157

#androidRules